# calling a method within CFC Failing, but creating it as an object is working fine

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

Getting something really strange that I just can't work out.

I have 3 methods within a CFC (guest.cfc):

```
- save
- create
- update
```

I pass an argumentCollection to the save method.

```
saveGuest = objGuest.save(argumentcollection=guestStruct)
```

If it includes an Identier, it passes the argumentCollecion to the update method, if it doesn't then it passes the collection to the create method.

This is working fine when called from one place int the app, but when I created a new call to the save method, the create method works fine, but if an ID is passed in the update method is called I receive an error that the UPDATE variable does not exists.

But, if I change the way I call it by creating an object of the cfc, it works..

so..

```
saveObject =  update(argumentCollection = arguments;
```

Does not work.  Receive an error that the update variable does not exist.

```
saveObject =  createObject("component",'guest').update(argumentCollection = arguments);
```

DOES work.

note that both these calls are occuring within the guest.cfc itself.

This issue doesn't occur when I pass a form struct to the save method, but does occur when I pass it a standard struct (constructed from an XML import).

Very strange.

Anyone have any ideas on what might causing this?

---

EDIT 24 April - Added Code for guest.cfc

---

```
<cffunction name="save" output="false" access="remote" hint="save guest">
    <cfargument name="title" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="first_name" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="surname" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="dob" type="any" required="false" default="NULL" />
    <cfargument name="partner_first_name" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="partner_surname" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="partner_dob" type="any" required="false" default="NULL" />
    <cfargument name="address_1" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="address_2" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="address_3" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="city" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="state" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="postcode" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="country" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="phone_bh" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="phone_ah" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="phone_mob" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="fax" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="email" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="business" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="notes" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="referer" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="prospect" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="occasion" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="occasion_date" type="any" required="false" default="NULL" />


    <!---pass to Create or Save--->
    <cfif NOT isdefined("arguments.guest_id") OR arguments.guest_id EQ "0">
        <cfset saveObject =  create(argumentCollection = arguments) />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset saveObject =  update(argumentCollection = arguments) />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn saveObject>

</cffunction>


<!---CREATE--->
<cffunction name="create" output="false" access="private" returntype="struct" hint="Create a New Item">
    <cfargument name="provider_id" type="any" required="false" default="#session.providerID#" />
    <cfargument name="ext_ref_id" type="any" required="false" default="NULL" />
    <cfargument name="tstamp" type="any" required="false" default="#session.tStamp#" />

    <cfif isValid('date',arguments.occasion_date)>
        <cfset iOccasionDate = createODBCDateTime(arguments.occasion_date)>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset iOccasionDate = "NULL">
    </cfif>

    <cfset returnStruct = StructNew()>

    <cfquery name="insertGuest" datasource="#Application.ds#">
        INSERT INTO guest (provider_id, ext_ref_id, title, first_name, surname, full_name, partner_first_name, partner_surname, partner_full_name, address_1, address_2, address_3, city, state, postcode, country, phone_bh, phone_ah, phone_mob, fax, email, company, notes, referer, prospect, occasion, occasion_date, tstamp)
        VALUES (#provider_id#, #ext_ref_id#, '#arguments.title#', '#arguments.first_name#', '#arguments.surname#', '#arguments.first_name# #arguments.surname#', '#arguments.partner_first_name#', '#arguments.partner_surname#', '#arguments.partner_first_name# #arguments.partner_surname#', '#arguments.address_1#', '#arguments.address_2#', '#arguments.address_3#', '#arguments.city#', '#arguments.state#', '#arguments.postcode#', '#arguments.country#', '#arguments.phone_bh#', '#arguments.phone_ah#', '#arguments.phone_mob#', '#arguments.fax#', '#arguments.email#', '#arguments.company#', '#arguments.notes#', '#arguments.referer#', '#arguments.prospect#', '#arguments.occasion#', #iOccasionDate#, #CreateODBCDateTime(tstamp)#)
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery name="guest" datasource="#Application.ds#">
        SELECT max(guest_id) as id
        FROM guest
        WHERE provider_id = #provider_id#
    </cfquery>

    <cfset returnStruct.id = #guest.id#>
    <cfreturn returnStruct>

</cffunction>



<!---UPDATE--->
<cffunction name="update" output="false" access="private" returntype="struct" hint="Update an existing item">

    <!---general details--->
    <cfquery name="update" datasource="#Application.ds#">
        UPDATE guest
        SET provider_id = provider_id

            <cfif isdefined("arguments.title")>
                ,title = '#arguments.title#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.first_name")>
                ,first_name = '#arguments.first_name#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.surname")>
                ,surname = '#arguments.surname#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.full_name")>
                ,full_name = '#arguments.full_name#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.dob")>
                ,dob = #formDate2odbcDate(arguments.dob)#
            </cfif>

            <cfif isdefined("arguments.partner_first_name")>
                ,partner_first_name = '#arguments.partner_first_name#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.partner_surname")>
                ,partner_surname = '#arguments.partner_surname#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.partner_full_name")>
                ,partner_full_name = '#arguments.partner_full_name#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.partner_dob")>
                ,partner_dob = #formDate2odbcDate(arguments.partner_dob)#
            </cfif>

            <cfif isdefined("arguments.address_1")>
                ,address_1 = '#arguments.address_1#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.address_2")>
                ,address_2 = '#arguments.address_2#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.address_3")>
                ,address_3 = '#arguments.address_3#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.city")>
                ,city = '#arguments.city#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.state")>
                ,state = '#arguments.state#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.postcode")>
                ,postcode = '#arguments.postcode#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.country")>
                ,country = '#arguments.country#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.phone_bh")>
                ,phone_bh = '#arguments.phone_bh#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.phone_ah")>
                ,phone_ah = '#arguments.phone_ah#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.phone_mob")>
                ,phone_mob = '#arguments.phone_mob#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.fax")>
                ,fax = '#arguments.fax#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.email")>
                ,email = '#arguments.email#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.subscribe_email_broadcast")>
                ,subscribe_email_broadcast = '#arguments.subscribe_email_broadcast#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.company")>
                ,company = '#arguments.company#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.notes")>
                ,notes = '#arguments.notes#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.prospect")>
                ,prospect = '#arguments.prospect#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.occasion")>
                ,occasion = '#arguments.occasion#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isdefined("arguments.occasion_date")>
                ,occasion_date = #formDate2odbcDate(arguments.occasion_date)#
            </cfif>

        WHERE guest_id = #arguments.guest_id#
    </cfquery>

    <cfset returnStruct = structNew()>
    <cfset returnStruct.id = arguments.guest_id>
    <cfreturn returnStruct>

</cffunction>
```

Comment: Jason: Could you post your guest.cfc code? It's a bit tough to tell what might be at play here without seeing a bit more (at least for me :). Thanks!

Comment: `saveObject =  update(argumentCollection = arguments;` is missing a parenthesis.

Comment: If possible post the code.  Does the issue go away if you name your update method update2 temporarily?

Comment: Further to my answer - please can you provide an example of a "working" and a "broken" argument structure?

Comment: hey guys.. sorry for taking so long to get to this.. got buried in something else and couldn't get back to this one..  I still haven't been able to work this one out...  I have been able to get around it by using the work around described in my post, but would be interesting to see what the actual cause of this is.. See edit in original post for inclusion of guest.cfc code.  Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CF, when inside a function and you write things like `<cfset iOccasionDate = ... >` and `<cfquery name="insertGuest" ...>` you are creating these in the **global** variables scope of that CFC/template.

You need to write either `<cfset var iOccasionDate = ... >` or `<cfset local.iOccasionDate = ... >` or `<cfquery name="local.insertGuest" ...>` to ensure they are created in the **local** variable scope for the function, and don't overwrite other variables.

Your specific problem is because you have this:

```
<cfquery name="update" datasource="#Application.ds#">
```

So you're overwriting your update function with an update query.

A few quick things to note:

- The local scope works in CF9 and above. If you're in CF8 or below you need to mimic it by writing `<cfset var local = StructNew() />` at the top of your function.
- If you use [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org/) or [OpenBD](http://www.openbluedragon.org/) there are settings to change the default behaviour to always create in local scope (which avoids the need for var/local scoping), but ACF does not have this option (yet?)
- **Use cfqueryparam!** - Simon has already mentioned this, but it's important enough to be repeated. You should *always* handle data based on where it will be used - to prevent intentional and accidental injection attacks - and for cfquery that means using cfqueryparam.

Comment: +1 had not noticed overwriting the "update" - this is why in code review I am very strict on scoping!

Comment: Peter, this was it.. obvious now that you point it out.  thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to be more precise without samples of the CFC code and the calling code, however I'd be inclined to suggest that you check the init() of your component.  Have you got an init() method, and are you calling it?  For example, outline of a component definition

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="init" access="public">
        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="save" access="public">
        <!--- logic --->
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="create" access="public">
        <!--- logic --->
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="update" access="public">
        <!--- logic --->
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

This would then be called by either of the following

```
<cfscript>
    // This will work in CF9 upwards
    objCFC = new guest(/* add any arguments you have in the init() method here */);
    objCFC.update(......);

    // This also works
    objCFC = CreateObject('component','guest').init(/* add any arguments you have in the init() method here */);
    objCFC.update(......);
</cfscript>
```

**edit following your example**

That CFC is nasty.  There are various glaring issues.

1. You are relying on application/session scope within the CFC thus forcing it to rely on global variables.  This is what an init() method is used for among other things, as you could `init(datasource, provider_id, ext_ref_id, tstamp)`, store those in `variables.` scope, and thus it will no longer be vulnerable to variables being undefined outside the CFC
2. You are using a LOT of VARCHAR fields with NO escaping whatsoever with a cfc with remote access permitted.  This is quite vulnerable to SQL injection.  Mr Bobby Tables can show you why this is bad ( http://bobby-tables.com/ )
3. You keep using string value NULL.  If you pass this through into a database within a varchar/quotes then it will be stored as 'NULL' and not as a database NULL value

All in all, the best course of action would be to rewrite this component.  The code changes on anything that uses the component will be minimal to the point of having to add in an init() and maybe removing some arguments however you will find the stability of it improved and all being well this odd issue will disappear.

Comment: Simon, thanks.. no, there is no init() method.  I do init objects now when calling, but these cfc's are quite old and generally have been doing what they need to do reliably for years.. so somewhat reluctant to edit them too much. Do you think not having the init method may be causing the problem?  Might be worth a play.  Thanks again!

Comment: First up, cfqueryparam. http://bobby-tables.com/ - regarding your CFC, some further info http://forums.adobe.com/thread/434078

Comment: _"so somewhat reluctant to edit them "_ - why are you reluctant? You'll always have the old version in source control and you'll run your test suites before deployment to ensure they still function the same, so there shouldn't be a need to worry...

Comment: Simon, thanks for your many great suggestions and I agree..  This isn't an App I am contracted to maintain, only been called in to get this particular issue fixed.    The clients are not wanting anything changed unless necessary as they want to avoid a full system test..  Thanks again!!

Comment: @Jason understandable however at the least the cfqueryparam's do NEED to be used to reduce/remove the risk of adverse side-effects.  Would hope you'll at least notify them that there are major security issues which need addressing.  If I saw this in a piece of code I was modifying for a client, I would **never** allow any changes to go up without correcting it.  Especially when the method is flagged to be remotely accessable

Comment: Thanks Simon, appreciated!  I have flagged the need to do a 'whole of cfc'  review .. infact, whole of lots of cfc reviews :), which may happen, but not holding our breaths.  This cfc is being used in an offline app, so security not a major concern.  Thanks again Simon!